# two match and with queries return no results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With my following query, I expected a `r` to be an array and `t` to be a number. But when I run the query, it just shows (no changes, no records).

When run individually, their output is as expected. So what is wrong with my query?

```
MATCH 
    (a:Account { 
            id : $account_id 
        })
    -[:MEMBER]->
    (n:Workspace)
WITH 
    COLLECT(n) AS nodes, 
    COUNT(n) AS total
MATCH 
    (n:Workspace { 
        account_id: $account_id 
    })
WITH
    nodes + COLLECT(n) AS r,
    total + COUNT(n) AS t
RETURN r, t
```

Comment: No change/ no records indicates that one or both MATCH statement haven't found any results... try changing them to OPTIONAL MATCH to avoid this problem

Comment: @TomažBratanič that solved it, thanks